# Почему не видно python если запускать cmd в папке?

Tags: python, windows, cmd

Запускаю python через start python видно:

```
C:\Users\SOAPTESTER>python -V
Python 3.5.3
```

Запускаю в папке с помошью "shift+правая кнопка мыши"/oppen command window here:

```
D:\LnP>python -V
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Подскажите в чем проблема? И как это исправить

Если из первого варианта перехожу в папку D:\LnP то все работает также. Результат зависит только от того где вызвать изначально cmd.

Comment: Пропишите в PATH  путь до Python

Comment: Он уже в Path. Его же в первом случае видно

Comment: Покажите `sys.executable` в первом случае. Одно значение получаете для `whoami` команды в обоих случаях? Покажите: `echo %PATH%`, `ftype Python.File`, `assoc .py`. Работает ли `py` команда?
 Покажите как у вас Питон в регистре прописан. [Пример кода](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0514/#sample-code). Простое объяснение: explorer ещё не обновил переменные окружения с тех пор как система запустилась (проверить можно перегрузив систему). [Opening command prompt since Windows Explorer: why are environment variables not updated?](https://superuser.com/q/954079/13868)

Answer (score 0):

Да потому что, когда ты устанавливал пайтон указал установку для конкретного пользователя, а тебе нужно было указать для всех